# Sending Cookies over WCF using the ChannelFactory

Tags: cookies, wcf-client, channelfactory

I use an IOC container which provides me with IService.
In the case where IService is a WCF service it is provided by a channel factory
When IService lives on the same machine it is able to access the same cookies and so no problem however once a WCF Service is called it needs to be sent those cookies.

I've spent a lot of time trying to find a way to send cookies using a channel factory and the only way I could find that works is the following

```
var cookie = _authenticationClient.GetHttpCookie();
HttpRequestMessageProperty httpRequestProperty = new HttpRequestMessageProperty();
httpRequestProperty.Headers.Add(HttpRequestHeader.Cookie, cookie.Name + "=" + cookie.Value);
using(var scope = new OperationContextScope((IClientChannel)_service))
{
   OperationContext.Current.OutgoingMessageProperties[HttpRequestMessageProperty.Name] = httpRequestProperty;
   var result = _service.Add(details);
   if (result.Result == RPGResult.Success)
   {
       return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home", result.Id);
   }
}
```

The problem with me using that method is that I have to know that I'm calling a WCF Service which is not always the case. I've tried writing a wrapper for the ChannelFactory that opens a new operationcontextscope when it creates a new service and various other solutions but nothing has worked.

Anyone have any experience with sending cookies over WCF Services?

I found a solution involving using SilverLight, unfortunately I'm not using silverlight, the solution is here: http://greenicicleblog.com/2009/10/27/using-the-silverlight-httpclient-in-wcf-and-still-passing-cookies/
Unfortunately standard .net doesn't contain the IHttpCookieContainerManager interface

Ideally I would be able to use something similar,i.e. I would be able to tell the channelfactory to pass a cookie whenever it opened.

If anyone has a better way to pass a token that is used for authentication that would be appreciated too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have a solution where I create a proxy class of IService and then every time a method on IService is called it invokes the proxy created by the channel factory but the call itself is wrapped in an operationcontextscope just like the one I have in my question.
I used the proxy factory from this link  http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/dynamicproxy.aspx